# django about the "can't import settings 'test.settings'

Tags: python, mysql

When I try to use Django to test a website, it reports an error.

```
python manage.py shell
```

It reports that:

> Error: Could not import settings 'test.settings' (Is it on sys.path?): No module named settings

But when I use a Python script to find the 'test.settings', I can't find it:

```
Python 2.7.3 (default, Sep 26 2012, 21:53:58)
>>> import sys
>>> print sys.path

> ['',
> '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/distribute-0.6.35-py2.7.egg',
> '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages', '/usr/bin/python2.7',
> '/home/hua/django/mysite/~share', '/usr/lib/python2.7',
> '/usr/lib/python2.7/plat-linux2', '/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-tk',
> '/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-old', '/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload',
> '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages',
> '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/setuptools-0.6c11-py2.7.egg-info',
> '/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages',
> '/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/PIL',
> '/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/gst-0.10',
> '/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/gtk-2.0',
> '/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/ubuntu-sso-client']
>>>
```

Comment: Can you post the structure of your directory? Does the folder `test` have both an `__init__.py` file and a `settings.py` file?

Comment: I install the django, I use the script "django-admin.py startproject mysite" . It worked, it has an "__init__" !

Comment: Do you have a folder called `mysite`?

Comment: yeah,the folder has created!

Comment: I try to delete the "test.settings", but cannot find it.I'm a Beginer!

Comment: You shouldn't create a project named test because there's a standard library named test and that can cause issues.

Comment: Edit your question and add the rest of the error message including the line numbers and file names in the traceback.

Answer (score 0):

Django creates files and folders that should not be renamed. Edit your `manage.py` file:

```
os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "mysite.settings")
```

Comment: #!/usr/bin/env python
   import os
   import sys
   if __name__ == "__main__":
       os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "mysite.settings") 
       from django.core.management import execute_from_command_line
       execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
### 
My os.environ is right! It looks it not this wrong.